# What is wrong with the WHILE Loop on PLSQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, while-loop, sparse-matrix

I'm practicing collections on PL/SQL, and now I've code a simple WHILE Loop to print on screen the values of the sparse associative array. I received the following error: Oracle Error -06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: NULL index table key value. The results were printed on screen but oracle error as well. Thanks.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE

  TYPE type_football_players IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(45)
       INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

  v_costademarfil_2006 type_football_players;

  v_counter PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN

  v_costademarfil_2006(9)  := 'Kone';
  v_costademarfil_2006(10) := 'Yapi Yapo';
  v_costademarfil_2006(11) := 'Drogba';
  v_costademarfil_2006(14) := 'Kone';
  v_costademarfil_2006(15) := 'Dindane';
  v_costademarfil_2006(19) := 'Toure';
  v_costademarfil_2006(21) := 'Eboue';

  v_counter := v_costademarfil_2006.FIRST;

  WHILE v_costademarfil_2006(v_counter) IS NOT NULL
  LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_costademarfil_2006(v_counter));

        v_counter := v_costademarfil_2006.NEXT(v_counter);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

> Informe de error - ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: NULL
>   index table key value ORA-06512: at line 48
>   06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
>   *Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
>              occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
>              assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
>              attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
>              declared NUMBER(2).
>   *Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
>              that values do not violate constraints.

```
Kone Yapi Yapo Drogba Kone Dindane Toure Eboue
```

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2009/09-sep/o59plsql-083841.html

Comment: @OldProgrammer Thanks for share this article. I have new ideas for coding now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `WHILE` loop condition is incorrect.

You need to check if `v_counter` is NOT NULL, not if `v_costademarfil_2006(v_counter)` is NOT NULL.

The final time around the loop, `v_counter` is NULL and so `v_costademarfil_2006( NULL )` is evaluated.  This leads to the error after printing all the names.

Comment: @Rattlesnake if this solves your problem, click the tick to accept this answer.